# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (62x12288 and 784x512)

Tags: python, pytorch

The images I put into the network are 64x64. Apparently I can't do this this is where it has the error, I'm just using the tutorial model.

Python File:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.io import read_image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch
from torch import nn    
import torch.nn.functional as F
from PIL import Image

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Custom Set: Length={len(self)}>"

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label
device = (
    "cuda"
    if torch.cuda.is_available()
    else "mps"
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available()
    else "cpu"
)
print(f"Using {device} device")

# Define model
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64*64, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)

dataset = CustomImageDataset("./Mr_Ai/dataset.csv", "./Mr_Ai/dataset/", ToTensor())
train_size = int(0.6 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_set, test_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])
batch_size = 64

# Create data loaders.
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=batch_size)

print(model)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
def test(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
epochs = 5
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```

Download the project:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C3El174RvMbTL0K4mE8-JlSUdNC5RP28/view?usp=sharing

Just run this code and it should error.

I tried changing it around but it didn't work. I want it just to run but it doesn't.

Comment: You should post a reproducible example and full error traceback. The code as is is functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are RGB images, which means you need `3*64*64` instead of `64*64`.